# Import XML Address Book fails on Brother MFC-L8900CDW copier

Tags: network-printer, multi-function-printer

I have a Brother MFC-L8900CDW multifunction copier (print/scan/fax) that has a built-in address book of email addresses to use as targets for delivering scan jobs. I need to update all of the addresses (domain change), and it's time-consuming to do this on the touch panel.

When logged into the web-based admin interface, I see that I can import and export the address book as XML, which I could edit more easily. As an initial test, I tried exporting the address book and re-importing the files without making any changes, and I got this error message.

> **Import error**
>   Possible reasons:
>   - Invalid or corrupt import file
>   - Wrong destination selected
>   - selected group file has no members
>   - Invalid number of group members

This is surprising -- does that mean the copier is providing me with a bad export?

I thought my problem might be with "Invalid number of group members" because I don't use groups at all on this copier, so I created a single group with a single member, but I got the same result again when retrying the import/export process.

Is there some kind of trick I can use to get this to work, or am I stuck with needing to update each entry using the touch panel on the device?

I'm using Safari 13 on macOS Catalina 10.15. I also tried Microsoft Edge Legacy on Windows 10 Pro and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing all of the following:

- Update the firmware to 1.19 (from 1.06). *This didn't seem to make a difference though.*
- Remove two shortcuts from the touch panel that referenced entries in the address book. *I think this is really what helped.*
- Clear all entries in the address book.
- Use Google Chrome or Firefox or Microsoft Edge. *Still fails in macOS Safari!*